# Solving a div positioning issue

Tags: css, html

I have a test site here:

http://www.hugoproject.com/test.html

I'm trying to put a second row of the book icons beneath the first, but whatever I try doesn't work. To clarify the situation, the following code makes a single book icon appear:

```
<div class="project">
<a href="#" class="HS" class="project-link">Arrow<span></span></a>
</div>
```

When I have two sets of the code, two icons appear, when there are three sets of the code three icons appear. But if I have four or more sets of the code only three icons appear! I want for the extra sets of code to make icons beneath the first three.

Also at the moment when you resize the browser window this makes the top row of icons resize dynamically. I'd like to keep this feature and make both rows of icons fit on the one page such that there is no scroll bar.

Any ideas?

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
<div id="home-projects-wrapper">

 <h1 class="home">Hello! My name is Brandon</h1>

<div id="home-projects">
<div id="projects" class="circle">
<div class="project-group">

<div class="project">
<a href="#" class="HS" class="project-link">Arrow<span></span></a>
</div>

<div class="project">
<a href="#" class="HS" class="project-link">Arrow<span></span></a>
</div>
                                               <div class="project">
<a href="#" class="HS" class="project-link">Arrow<span></span></a>
</div>

<div class="project">
<a href="#" class="HS" class="project-link">Arrow<span></span></a>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
  transition: left .3s;
  -moz-transition: left .3s;
  -webkit-transition: left .3s;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
  #container.open {
    left: 270px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: left .3s;
    -moz-transition: left .3s;
    -webkit-transition: left .3s;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
#content {
width: 80%;
max-width: 1170px;
margin: 7% auto;
position: relative;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 22px;
color: #777777;
}
        .page-template-page-templateshome-php #content {
            width: auto;
            margin: 0 auto;
        position: static;
    }
    .single-post #content {
       width: 60%;
    }

#home-projects {
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
    #projects {
        width: 100%;
    } 
  .project-group {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
  }
.project {
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
 width: 33.3%;
 height:100%;
}
    .project-link {
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-color: #adadad;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 80%;
    }
    .circle .project-link, .circle .project-link .hover {
        border-radius: 100%;
        -moz-border-radius: 100%;
        -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    }
    .project-link .hexagon-top {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        border-style: solid;
        border-bottom-color: transparent;
        border-left-color: #dfdfdf;
        border-right-color: #dfdfdf;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    .project-link .hexagon-bottom {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        border-style: solid;
        border-top-color: transparent;
        border-left-color: #dfdfdf;
        border-right-color: #dfdfdf;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        z-index: 2;
    }
        .project-link .hover {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            font-size: 14px;
            text-align: center;
            color: #fff;
            background: #ec6136;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            display: block;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: all .3s;
            -moz-transition: all .3s;
            -webkit-transitin: all .3s;
        }
            .project-link .hover-text {
                display: block;
                margin-top: 45%;
            }
            .project-link .hover-text:after {
                content: '>';
                font-family: 'icon';
                font-size: 12px;
                margin-left: 15px;
            }
        .project-link:hover > .hover {
            opacity: .9;
        }
```

Comment: Your page does not demonstrate the problem you are having, so it is difficult to answer your question - because there isn't one.

Comment: Your revision looks helpful, but the web page at http://www.hugoproject.com/test.html won't load at all for me now.

Answer (score 0):

I would set up a `div` container for the books with a set width equal to the width of the `books` + `margins`.

Then set the book `div`s to `"float: left;"` and it should put 3 books per line.

If you want to keep the auto scaling you should do all this with percentages like you are currently doing.

Comment: I didn't think of this - thanks. Something like this?:

    <div class="testing"> in the html

then for CSS:

    .testing {
    width: 1000px;
    float: left;
    }

I tried the above and it didn't work

Comment: Keep it simple, just one div to contain all the books that has the width to hold 3 per line. Then on the book div you need to have the float: left;

Comment: Thanks for the help but it doesn't work. I've incorporated your suggestions into my page 
http://www.hugoproject.com/test.html
you can view it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue with what you have now, just remove position:absolute from .project-group

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a height for your blocks, i.e.

```
.project {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 33.3%;
    height: 290px;
}

.HS {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 290px;
    background-image: url("http://www.hugoproject.com/ftp1/images/icons.png");
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-size: 800%;
}
```

That will not completely solve your issue though. Maybe you want to use images inside the boxes instead of a background image/icon. You can also always calculate new dimensions with JavaScript/jQuery.